# Has select always included the label on drop down lists?

Tags: profile

Maybe I am just noticing things now but has select always included the label on drop down lists? I thought it used to say -none- when none was selected.

Example from dmaster demo
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes that was one of the many changes in 5.31 related to screen readers and buttons and such. https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/17675

It also inadvertently made all my contacts [appear to be from Afghanistan](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/2118).

Comment: It makes our forms look ugly. Are screen readers not able to read the labels beside the multiselect? At the very least, it could make Select with an uppercase S.

Comment: The PR above mentions that there are some longer term goals with Select2 which might make it unnecessary. And it mentions it might be awkward but is less awkward than the screen reader saying "None press button". You can open an issue or PR about the uppercase.